# How to transpose one column (multiple rows) to multiple columns?

Tags: powershell

I have a file with the below contents:

```
0
ABC
1
181.12
2
05/07/16
3
1002
4
1211511108
6
1902
7
1902
10
hello
-1
0
ABC
1
1333.21
2
02/02/16
3
1294
4
1202514258
6
1294
7
1294
10
HAI
-1
...
```

I want to transpose the above file contents like below. The '-1' in above lists is the record separator which indicates the start of the next record.

```
ABC,181.12,05/07/16,1002,1211511108,1902,1902,hello
ABC,1333.21,02/02/16,1294,1202514258,1294,1294,HAI
...
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: You could use a language like F# or C# and write yourself a cmdlet for power shell. Or a simple .exe, depending on what you plan to do with the data next. In F# it would be like 20 lines max. If you don't have programming background, you might want to decide to pick up one language so you dont hit the ceiling with problems like that. Maybe you can do it in powershell directly - but in my experience it is not as long lasting a gain to learn a shell language, compared to learning a  real programming language and use it for the next 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file as a single string:

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' | Out-String
```

Split the content at `-1` lines:

```
$txt -split '(?m)^-1\r?\n'
```

Split each block at line breaks:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
}
```

Select the values at odd indexes (skip the number lines) and join them by commas:

```
$indexes = 1..$($arr.Count - 1) | Where-Object { ($_ % 2) -ne 0 }
$arr[$indexes] -join ','
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I'm just consolidating your above code. Is this correct?            $txt = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' | Out-String
$txt -split '(?m)^-1\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
}
$indexes = 1..$($arr.Count - 1) | Where-Object { ($_ % 2) -ne 0 }
$arr[$indexes] -join ','

Comment: @MaheshMohan Had you actually tried the code you would have noticed that it can't possibly be correct, because it would have returned just the last record from the input file. Move selection and join into the loop.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I ran the above consolidated code and it didn't return any and not the last record. May I know which selection are you referring here? Kindly let me know please.

Comment: Please go find a PowerShell tutorial, because you're obviously in *way* over your head. SO is not the right place for you when you don't even understand the basics of the language you're using.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thank you so much for your time. I have got the result. Once again, Thanks!